# What is keeping my simple if statement from working?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, document-ready

Does anyone see any issues or have any idea why it won't work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   if (location.href=="http://www.example.com") {alert("test test test");
   } else {
   document.location = "http://www.example.com/test";
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly is it doing and what do you expect it to do? Are you using a proper URL in your actual code?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is useless. Tell us what you expect it to do, what it's actually doing, how that differs from what you expected and what error messages you're seeing (if any). If you're having trouble figuring out which branch of your if statement is being followed, add some basic debugging statements via `alert` or `console.log`.

Comment: @Sam: in my version of Chrome, both `document.location` and `location` as an alias for `window.location` work as expected.

Comment: I'd like it to show the alert box if the url is "http://www.example.com" and direct to "http://www.example.com/test" if it the url is anything else

Comment: You should alert out location.href to an alert or to console.log to see what it's ACTUALLY returning as.  My guess is it's not what you think it is.  Could be a trailing slash etc ..

Comment: It´s `window.location.href`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Properties

Comment: @Stefan: that's definitely the more precise way to do it, but, at least in modern browsers, `window.location` is just a reference to the global variable `location`, so the given sample should work just fine. Then again, I don't have IE available to test right now, so who knows what kind of nonsense it could pull?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       if (window.location.href =="http://www.example.com") {alert("test test test");
       } else {
           window.location = "http://www.example.com/test";
       }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: While we can't *really* know what's going on in such a vague question, I'm not sure is the issue: in my version of Chrome, testing against `location.href` works just fine.

Comment: If the problem is in IE (?) then it can work fine in every other browser but IE... But we don't know so I just wrote what i think is correct :)

Comment: Huh. But I guess if this fixed it, TIL IE doesn't like `window.location`. Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd go to the website (using Chrome for example) and open up the console (F12) and type in "location.href" you will notice that the location is ending with a slash, as it's where you are being redirected by most http webservers. So, check for url with a trailing slash

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       if (location.href=="http://www.example.com/") {alert("test test test");
       } else {
       document.location = "http://www.example.com/test";
       }
    });
    </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why wait for document ready event to change the current location?

I suggest you skip that part and verify the property value by outputing it using `console.log()` or a simple `alert`.

Something like this would do;

```
console.log('Current location =', window.location.href, window.location.href == 'http://www.example.com'); // DEBUG

if (window.location.href != 'http://www.example.com') {
  // redirect
  window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com/test';
}
```

Answer (score -4):

why don't you try a self evoquing anonymous function :

```
(function(){
 if (location.href=="http://www.example.com") {
    alert("test test test");
 } else {
     document.location = "http://www.example.com/test";
 }
})();
```

Comment: This is not shorthand for `document.ready`; it's just declaring a function that instantly calls itself. This should not resolve the issue.

Comment: This is *not* shorthand for `document.ready`. Your code will almost certainly run *before* the document is ready. You're only introducing additional errors with this code.

Comment: well it isn't why don't we let him try it with this self evoquing anonymous function then ?

Comment: Because the function in question won't be fixed by invoking it earlier. Your answer can't possibly affect the problem the user is having. You shouldn't post "try this" answers if you don't really understand what the problem is, that doesn't help anybody. It only adds confusion.

Comment: I find it unlikely that the bug lies, of all places, in jQuery's DOM-ready function. Sure, anything's worth trying from a philosophical standpoint, but I'd bet serious cash on this having nothing to do with it — in fact, I'd consider taking odds on this making the problem *worse*, depending on the real-world code that runs instead of the alert.